# text around corner css, position absolute and responsive

Tags: html, css

I would like to replicate this result : https://prnt.sc/j36zjg

I have this code but I have some problem, and the text does not follow the square, but goes where it wants.

```
<div style="position:relative">
<p style="position: absolute; right: 20px; top: -235px; transform: 
rotate(90deg); color: #05c6bf; font-family: rubikregular; font-size: 
40pt;">CONTACTS</p>
</div>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must work on top and right values, because they refer to the element before the 90deg. rotation.

here is the code that works:

```
<div style="position:relative;background:yellow;width:300px;height:300px;">
<p style="position: absolute; right: -70px; top: 100px; transform: 
rotate(90deg);background:#ccc; color: #05c6bf; font-family: rubikregular; font-size: 
20pt;padding:5px;">CONTACTS</p>
</div>
```

and you can check it in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/4fkwqrL0/6/